# Form submissoin with react, redux, firestore - collection not created in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

When I submit this form, the new user is created in firebase authentication, but the corresponding document in the ‘staff’ collection is not created.

I'm using Redux and Thunk middleware. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

StaffSignup.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import returnStore from '../../redux/store/configureStore'
import { addStaff } from '../../redux/actions/tutorActions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { signUpStaff } from '../../redux/actions/authActions'

import Select from 'react-select'
class StaffSignup extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.store = returnStore()
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.props.staffSignUp(e.target.id,e.target.value)
    }

    //React-Select OnChange Handles
    handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()

        {
            this.props.signUpTutor(this.store.getState().tutor.tutors)
            e.target.reset()
        }

    }



    render(){
        return(
            <Fragment>
                <section className="page-section mt-5" id="tutorSignUp">

                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="text-center">
                            <h2 className="section-heading">Staff Signup</h2>
                            <h3 className="section-subheading text-muted"></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-around row-hl">
                            <div className="p-4 item-hl"></div>
                            <div className="p-4 item-hl">
                                <Form.Group className="mt-2 mb-2">
                                    <label htmlFor="email">Email *</label>
                                    <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        id="email"
                                        name="email"
                                        type="email"
                                        placeholder="Your Email"
                                        required="required"
                                        data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address."
                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    />
                                </Form.Group>

                                <Form.Group className="mt-2 mb-2">
                                    <label htmlFor="password">Password *</label>
                                    <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        id="password"
                                        name="password"
                                        type="password"
                                        placeholder="Your Password"
                                        required="required"
                                        data-validation-required-message="Please enter your password."
                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    />
                                </Form.Group>

                                 <Form.Group className="mt-2 mb-4">
                                    <label htmlFor="phone">Phone *</label>
                                    <input  className="form-control"
                                            id="phone"
                                            type="phone"
                                            name="phone"
                                            placeholder="For emergency contact only."
                                            required="required"
                                            data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number."
                                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    />
                                </Form.Group>


                                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-capitalize mt-4">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="p-4 item-hl"></div>
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                </section>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth: state.firebase.auth,
        //   authError: state.auth.authError,
    }
}

//Specify the method(s) that we want to add to the props
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        staffSignUp: (staff) => {
            dispatch(signUpStaff(staff))
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StaffSignup)
```

authActions.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"

export const signUpStaff = (newUser) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore()
        const firebase = getFirebase()
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            newUser.email,
            newUser.password
        ).then((resp) => {
            return firestore.collection('staff').doc(resp.user.uid).set({
                email: newUser.email,
                phone: newUser.phone
            })
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('signup success')
        }).catch( err => {
            console.log('signup error: ', err)
        })
    }
}
```

addStaff.js

```
export const addStaff = (id,value) =>
    ({
        type:'ADD_INFO',
        id: id,
        value: value
    })
```

configureStore.js

```
import rootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { getFirestore, reduxFirestore } from 'redux-firestore'
import firebaseConfig from '../../config/firebaseConfig'

export default () => {
  
  const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
        reduxFirestore(firebaseConfig),
        )
    )
    return store
}
```

rootReducer.js

```
import staffReducer from './tutorReducer'
import { firestoreReducer } from 'redux-firestore'
import { firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    staff: staffReducer,
})

export default rootReducer
```

staffReducer.js

```
const initState = {
    staff:
        {
            phone: '',
            email: '',
            status: 'active',
        }
};

const staffReducer = (state = initState, action) =>
{
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_INFO':
            return{
                tutors:
                    {
                        ...state.tutors,
                        [action.id]: action.value
                    }
            }


        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default staffReducer
```

Comment: is it generating any logs? if it is generating logs could you share them please?

Comment: @JoséSoní Nope, It's not generating any logs.

Comment: Could you please set some breakpoints , for example before the query is sent to Firestore and before printing the results to screen so you can get the actual values used for the query, and then the actual result of this queries, this will help to determine where in the code is the issue.